# Sorting JSON Response before show in table view controller - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

```
Rewards =     (
                {
            "Restaurant_ID" = 34;
            "Rewarded_Points" = 40;
            "Rewarded_Time" = "2015-11-23 09:16:00";
        },

           {
            "Restaurant_ID" = 40;
            "Rewarded_Points" = 60;
            "Rewarded_Time" = "2015-11-24 12:22:56";
          },
            {
            "Restaurant_ID" = 34;
            "Rewarded_Points" = 40;
            "Rewarded_Time" = "2015-11-24 12:22:56";
        }
);
```

im retrieving above response to variable and show in TableViewController using for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<rewards.count;i++){
        NSDictionary * rewardsObj = [rewards objectAtIndex:i];
        restId = [rewardsObj objectForKey:@"Restaurant_ID"];
        rewardedPoints = [rewardsObj objectForKey:@"Rewarded_Points"];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Current Output is showing same Restaurant ID again and again. i want if there is matching ID then those points need to be calculate sum.

`34 - Total Points : 40`

`40 - Total Points : 60`

`34 - Total Points : 40` //Again

but i want to sort it like below

`34 - Total Points : 80` // 40+40

`40 - Total Points : 60`

Comment: are u storing restId and rewardedPoints into array ?

Comment: @Venkat yes. if there is matching restId then rewarded points output sum of all of it.

Comment: u can create a dictionary with the key is the ID, then when parsing JSON to the dictionary, u can check if the key exist then do your SUM, else then make new pair, its the easiest and fastest way i can think of

Answer (score 2):

use `NSSortDescriptor` for your concept,

**Step -1**

initially select the key based on sort , for ex `Rewarded_Points` we take , and sort as `ascending` order.

```
NSSortDescriptor * Rewarded_Points =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Rewarded_Points"
                           ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:Rewarded_Points, nil];

 NSArray *sortedArrayOfDictionaries = [Rewards sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; // Rewards -> array of dictionary name

NSLog(@"final Value : %@", sortedArrayOfDictionaries);
```

for additional [Tutorial](http://krupanshusharma.blogspot.in/)

Comment: I submitted the partial answer, for your second query i have one doubt in here your date is differnet it is fine to add, else you try for omit the duplicate value based on keys...